# RESTEasy - Resource Class Register Failed when @Path is Marked in the Interface

Tags: jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I am using RESTEasy 2.0.1.GA on Jboss 4.3.0.GA. 
The interface that my resource class implemented looks like this:

```
@Path("/")
public interface CwindRestfulService {
@GET
@Path("accounts/{email}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Account getAccountInfo(@PathParam("email") String email) throws Exception;
}
```

When I set resteasy.scan=true in web.xml, it works fine. But it should be false with spring context. So now my web.xml is:

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype RestEasy Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>    
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>com.cwind.rest.CwindRestfulServiceImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And I got this error:

```
2014-02-20 18:10:23,303 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase]   Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
java.lang.RuntimeException: Class is not a root resource.  It, or one of its interfaces must be annotated with @Path: com.cwind.rest.CwindRestfulServiceImpl implements: com.cwind.rest.CwindRestfulService
```

It suggested that I missed @Path while actually I didn't. But when I put the annotation to the resource class it does work. I googled and found a solution in http://pilhuhn.blogspot.com/2011/06/seemingly-common-resteasy-error-and.html. It needs to add a @ApplicationPath annotation. Now my interface is in a third party lib so I can't modify it. Does anybody have some suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have not registered a Resteasy specific `SpringContextLoaderListener`.  This is required for Spring to register scanned resource classes with Resteasy.

Below is an example web.xml configuration (this uses annotation configuration, but will also work with xml configuration):

```
<!-- Spring Configuration -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>com.myapp.SpringConfig</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- RESTEasy Configuration -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- RESTEasy <-> Spring Connector (Needed so that RESTEasy has access to Spring managed beans!) -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- RESTEasy HTTP Request Processor Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then you simply annotate your resource classes for Spring either with `@Component` or `@Named` as shown below:

```
@Named
@Path("/")
public class MyResource implements CwindRestfulService 
{
   //Stuff Goes Here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Greg! Now it works. But still one thing, @Path must be added in the resource class, it won't work when the annotation is merely in the interface.