# java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003130: Class is not a root resource. error

Tags: java, resteasy

my java project uses resteasy version 3.1.4.Final since beginning. But now, I want to upgrade to 3.14.0.Final or to upper latest and non-vulnerable one. But for the time being, I have upgraded to 3.14.0.Final. Since I have upgraded, I'm getting this error in tomcat -

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003130: Class is not a root resource......
```

and so on when I run my some JMX that I created in JMeter.

Full Error is shown below -

```
{http-nio-38080-exec-1} ERROR : Servlet.init() for servlet [Resteasy] threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003130: Class is not a root resource.  It, or one of its interfaces must be annotated with @Path: com.app.resource.current.AppInstanceResource implements:
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:185) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.14.0.Final.jar:3.14.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:164) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.14.0.Final.jar:3.14.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addPerRequestResource(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:81) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.14.0.Final.jar:3.14.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registration(ResteasyDeployment.java:503) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.14.0.Final.jar:3.14.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:288) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.14.0.Final.jar:3.14.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:93) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.14.0.Final.jar:3.14.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:140) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.14.0.Final.jar:3.14.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:42) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.14.0.Final.jar:3.14.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1117) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:788) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:128) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.65]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
16:49:05.320 [Resteasy] {http-nio-38080-exec-1} ERROR : Allocate exception for servlet [Resteasy]
java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003130: Class is not a root resource.  It, or one of its interfaces must be annotated with @Path: morpho.ccmid.b2b.resource.current.AppInstanceResource implements:
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:185) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.14.0.Final.jar:3.14.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:164) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.14.0.Final.jar:3.14.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addPerRequestResource(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:81) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.14.0.Final.jar:3.14.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registration(ResteasyDeployment.java:503) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.14.0.Final.jar:3.14.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:288) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.14.0.Final.jar:3.14.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:93) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.14.0.Final.jar:3.14.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:140) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.14.0.Final.jar:3.14.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:42) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.14.0.Final.jar:3.14.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1117) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:788) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:128) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.65]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
```

**NOTE**: I found the similar question in which the solution was given to add SpringContextLoaderListener in web.xml but that didn't help me. It again throws some error in tomcat during runtime when my module loads. That error states something - classNotFoundException : SpringContextLoaderListener not found etc etc .....

Please help, how to resolve this error and get rid of this as well as upgrade the version to 3.14.0.Final.

I've tried the solution from this question [RESTEasy - Resource Class Register Failed when @Path is Marked in the Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905416/resteasy-resource-class-register-failed-when-path-is-marked-in-the-interface), but this didn't help.

Please someone suggest a new a better solution more specific to my work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Spring? I don't see Spring in the stack trace at least. I would also advise updating to 5.0.6.Final as that is the latest Jakarta REST 2.1 implementation.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins No Sir, I'm not using Spring. My project comprise of multiple modules, and only one of them is totally dependent upon spring, but not this one (having error). I will try on 5.0.6.Final and will let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Then the `SpringContextLoaderListener` won't really work for you since you're not using it , it's not on your class path. If you have issues with 5.0.6.Final, please let me know. You're welcome to open a discussion here too https://github.com/resteasy/resteasy/discussions.

Comment: Sure @JamesR.Perkins, I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `import javax.ws.rs.*;` switch to using `import jakarta.ws.rs.*;` - that did it for me. Update your dependency accordingly from maven.